# Forward Declaration (PIMPL) for External Libraries also used in Method Declarations?

Tags: c++, class, opencv, c++11, forward-declaration

I have looked at a significant number of posts regarding forward declarations/PIMPL, but haven't quite managed to get it to work with the external libraries I'm using. I want to create a shared library where the client does not need to include the external library headers.

This is what I currently have.

```
################
## myClass.h ##
################

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> ------> I want this header in the implementation file instead.

class A;
class B;
class C;

class __declspec(dllexport) myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    cv::Mat myFunction(cv::Mat &img);
private:
    A *_a;
    B *_b;
    C *_c;
};

################
## myClass.cpp ##
################

#include "myClass.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

myClass::myClass()
{
    _a = new A;
    _b = new B;
    _c = new C;
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    delete _a;
    delete _b;
    delete _c;
}

cv::Mat myClass::myFunction(cv::Mat &img){ ... }

################
## a.h ##
################

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ... -----> A's methods
};

################
## b.h ##
################

class B{ ... };

################

################
## c.h ##
################

class C{ ... };

################
```

Here's what I have tried (updated to show PIMPL)

```
################
## myClass.h ##
################

/*
namespace cv{
    class Mat; ------> Forward declaration of cv::Mat
}
*/

class __declspec(dllexport) myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    //cv::Mat myFunction(cv::Mat &img); ------> Get an error since I'm declaring an incomplete type cv::Mat.
private:
    class A;
    class B;
    class C;
    A *_a; --------------> PIMPL
    B *_b;
    C *_c;
    //std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat> _m; ---------> PIMPL
};

################
## myClass.cpp ##
################

#include "myClass.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

myClass::myClass()
{
    _a = new A();
    _b = new B();
    _c = new C();
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    delete _a;
    delete _b;
    delete _c;
}

################
## a.h ##
################

#include "myClass.h"

class myClass::A
{
public:
    A();
    ... -----> A's methods
};
```

Any assistance or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you just want `cv::Mat` then just include `#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>`. No need to include `opencv2/opencv.hpp` which probably contains a lot more header files.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @kiner_shah There are more, I was just simplifying the example. I don't really want the end user to have to include any external header files.

Comment: Not sure what application or library is this, but your interface then should contain classes which doesn't rely on external types. Link OpenCV statically and use its headers only in source files (.h and .cpp) which are anyways hidden to the end user.

Comment: @Osyotr With what I currently have, the end user has to include multiple <opencv/...hpp> headers along with my libraries header. I want to avoid this by having the external libraries in the implementation code instead. But I'm not sure how to go about it. There aren't many examples that use the forward declarations inside the class functions as well.

Comment: @RPH `myFunction` accepts `cv::Mat` by reference which implies that the user already includes opencv headers.

Comment: But the user must include the header anyway to use those OpenCV types. Libraries have dependencies, that is completely normal, why are you trying to hide them? You are setting yourself for the scenario where the user and your library are compiled against different versions and that will be a mess.

Comment: Also, `myFunction` returns `cv::Mat` by value, which implies that the caller needs to allocate storage for the return value. Which implies that in the translation unit of the caller, `cv::Mat` needs to be a complete type. Which implies this class needs to be defined there.

Comment: if you want to get rid of `cv::Mat` in your declaration, you would have to replace it by vectors or flat memory, or some other library's matrix type, or come up with your own matrix type... and then adapt that to `cv::Mat` internally.

Comment: If you want to hide the library, you need to hide the library types. You generally cannot forward declare types that you don't own, so you need to wrap them. Create your own `struct mymat { cv::Mat data; }`, forward-declare it in your header file, and define it in your implementation file. Also make sure the user can create and manipulate `mymat` objects so you need to provide a public interface for that.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. It makes sense now. I thought maybe the end user would use their own openCV version but I see now that would not be a good idea and I can rather provide the libraries.

Comment: Is it possible to hide `class A` `class B` `class C` forward declarations from the public interface ? The user is still able to see them since they're in the global space even though nothing can be done with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of the interface of your library is a function, that accepts an argument of type `cv::Mat` and returns `cv::Mat` by value. Suppose this simple code:

```
#include <myClass.h>  // your library header
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>  // OpenCV header

int main() {
  myClass o;
  cv::Mat input;
  cv::Mat result = o.myFunction(input);
}
```

> I want to create a shared library where the client does not need to include the external library headers.

How could a user write such code without including some OpenCV header where the `cv::Mat` class is defined? This is simply not possible.

Even if you redeclared/redefined `myFunction` to:

```
cv::Mat* myFunction(cv::Mat* img);
```

then, the user would still need to include OpenCV headers in their code to be able to create an input object pointed to by the function argument and work with the returned pointed-to output object.

The only possibility I can think of would be to wrap `cv::Mat` completely with your own library type and use it in your interface instead of `cv::Mat`. But then, users would need to use this type instead something well-known. Which would be very bad design in my opinion.

---

BTW, you mentioned PIMPL. But PIMPL is about something else. It's about hiding implementation details. Here, `cv::Mat` is a part of your library **interface**. You cannot hide interface, because then it wouldn't be interface any more.

Comment: Is it possible to hide `class A` `class B` `class C` forward declarations from the public interface ? The user is still able to see them since they're in the global space even though nothing can be done with them.

Comment: @RPH If those classes do not participate in your library interface, then yes, you can hide them. I would suggest here to use PIMPL. Then, you don't need to even declare those classes in your header file. You would only need to declare the implementation class, but this is typically a private nested class of its interface class, so no user can access it. Example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl.

Comment: I tried to implement PIMPL but I get an error `Allocation of incomplete type`. I have updated the 2nd part of my code to show how I tried to implement PIMPL for `class A`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @RPH The declared PIMPL `class A` is a nested class of `myClass`. The defined class in the header is an ordinary unnested `class A` completely unrelated to `myClass::A`.

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue, I didn't make `class A` a nested class of `myClass`. I have updated the code in my answer again. Seems to be working fine, although I didn't make use of smart pointers since I didn't really see the need to. I explicitly delete the pointers in `~myClass()` and I also didn't include destructors for `class A/B/C` since they don't create any internal pointers. Any other reason to use `std::unique_ptr<>` instead of what I have ? Thanks.